# JFrame not running properly inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to run a simple game where there is a server and a client talking to each other to do updates, at the moment I am not doing much between the server and the client just sending some meaningless stuff. My problem is that my 'clientframe' which extends `JFrame`, is not displaying properly when I try to make a new clientframe inside the run method of my 'slave' (the client) which is a thread. My clientframe works fine when it is run with its own main method but for some reason is draws a black screen with a small white rectangle in the top corner when I try to make a new clientframe inside the run method of the slave class. I realise this is not enough code to run it, and I have spent hours trying to debug it but I am stuck, thank you!

```
public final class Slave extends Thread {


private final Socket socket;
private NetworkHandler game;    
private DataOutputStream output;
private DataInputStream input;
private int uid;
private int totalSent;
private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;

private Update lastSentUpdate;

/**
 * Construct a slave connection from a socket. 
 * 
 * @param socket
 */
public Slave(Socket socket) {               
    this.socket = socket;               
}

public void run() {
    try {       

        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


            game = new NetworkHandler(NetworkHandler.Type.CLIENT);
            PlayableCharacter ch = game.getGameUtill().findCharacter(uid);

            ClientFrame frame = new ClientFrame(game, uid, true, ch);

            while(true){
                uid = input.readInt();      
                // now read the other players IDs
                int noPlayers = input.readInt();
                List<Integer> playerIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                for(; noPlayers>0; noPlayers--){
                    playerIds.add(input.readInt());
                }

                numbers = playerIds;
            }
        socket.close(); // release socket ... v.important!
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public List<Integer> getNumbers (){
    return numbers;
}

public int getUID(){
    return uid;
}
}


public class ClientFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private static final double FRAMEHEIGHTMODIFIER = 600.0 / 768;
private static final double ASPECTRATIO = 2;

private GameRunner runner;
private int clientsUID;
private RenderPanel renderPanel;
private boolean isClient;
private StatPanel statPanel;
private Dimension windowSize;

public ClientFrame(GameRunner network, int UID, boolean isClient,
        PlayableCharacter character) {
    super("Cat and Mouse");
    this.setLocation(new Point(50, 50));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("done setup");
    this.setDimensions();
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addPanels(character);
    this.clientsUID = UID;
    this.runner = network;
    this.isClient = isClient;
    this.setup();
}

private void setDimensions() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    if (screenSize == null) {
        System.out.println("screenSize is null");
    }
    System.out.println(screenSize.getHeight());
    int windowHeight = (int) (screenSize.getHeight() * FRAMEHEIGHTMODIFIER);
    int windowWidth = (int) (windowHeight * ASPECTRATIO);
    System.out.printf("Width: %d | Height: %d", windowWidth, windowHeight);
    windowSize = new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    this.setSize(windowSize);
    this.setPreferredSize(windowSize);
    System.out.println("dimensions set");
}

private void addPanels(PlayableCharacter character) {
    renderPanel = new RenderPanel(windowSize, this);

    // Create dimensions
    int panelHeight = (int) (1.0 / 2 * windowSize.getHeight());
    int statPanelWidth = (int) (1.0 / 6 * windowSize.getWidth());
    int invPanelWidth = (int) (1.0 / 24 * windowSize.getWidth());

    Dimension statPanelDim = new Dimension(statPanelWidth, panelHeight);
    Dimension invPanelDim = new Dimension(invPanelWidth, panelHeight);

    // Create locations
    int invLocationX = (int) (1.0 / 60 * windowSize.getWidth());
    int invPanelLocationY = (int) (3.0 / 8 * windowSize.getHeight());
    int statLocationX = (int) (49.0 / 60 * windowSize.getWidth());
    int statPanelLocationY = (int) (7.0 / 16 * windowSize.getHeight());

    InventoryPanel invPanel = new InventoryPanel(character, invPanelDim);
    invPanel.setLocation(invLocationX, invPanelLocationY);
    invPanel.setSize(invPanelDim);
    invPanel.setPreferredSize(invPanelDim);

    statPanel = new StatPanel(character);
    statPanel.setLocation(statLocationX, statPanelLocationY);
    statPanel.setSize(statPanelDim);
    statPanel.setPreferredSize(statPanelDim);

    this.add(invPanel);
    this.add(statPanel);
    this.add(renderPanel);
    System.out.println("panel set fine");
}

// @Override
// public void redraw(){
//
// }

/**
 * NOTE: may need to check when moving if moved to another room!! TODO
 */
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<GameItem> items = new ArrayList<GameItem>();
    items.add(new Food(2, 30));
    items.add(new Key(3));
    items.add(new Food(2, 30));

    PlayableCharacter character = new PlayableCharacter(1, null, " ", 3, 5,
            items);
    new ClientFrame(null, 0, false, character);
}


}
```

Comment: Swing thread violations, null layouts and key listener which are all going to work against you. Search for concurrency in Swing, SwingWorker, Laying out Containers and Key Bindings for enter solutions

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you're trying to do like this.

Any GUI operation must occur on the GUI (main) thread, and can't happen on a background thread. You should use `SwingWorker`, which has a means of running background operations on a background thread, and then invoking a `done()` method at the end that runs on the GUI thread to deal with GUI updates based on the result of the background computation.

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: I am not changing the frame from this slave class though, it actually doesn't matter where I put it, I just want to run the slave and the frame at the same time without breaking. If I used a SwingWorker (I don't know much about them but I have been trying to) I'm not sure how I would use it in this situation as the slave isn't actually doing anything to the frame other than making it? but even when I make the frame elsewhere, if I make a slave somewhere in the program also it still breaks

Comment: @Francinebc You need to create the `JFrame` on the GUI thread, and then not access it from anywhere except the GUI thread. Any time you touch it from another thread, you're causing trouble.

Comment: Hmmmmm I have tried doing that and it still breaks! If I use SwingWorker, do I make slave extend SwingWorker? What major thing in the slave class need to be changed other than changing the run() method into a doInBackground() I'm sorry I am finding this very confusing, I thought that threads could work concurrently with other operations?

Comment: @Francinebc I would be inclined to restructure it so that the `AsyncTask` is owned by the `JFrame`, rather than the other way round.

Comment: @chiastic-security In the end I got it working, I tried everyhting I could think of and on the web and the one that worked was having the clientframe setting up the slave but instead of slave extending Thread or implementing Runnable (or other various...) I had it holding a runnable inside of it:                            Runnable r = new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
  }
 };